# Copy embed and modify between chats discordjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to change some information on embed messages then transfer the message from channels, but when I try to transfer the message, I have this error:

```json
RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_NAME]: MessageEmbed field names must be non-empty strings.
```

I've trying like this:

```js
let title;
let fieldName;
let fieldValue;

if(message.channel.id == analiseChannelID && reaction.emoji.name === 'aprovada') {
  message.embeds.forEach(embeds => {
    let title = embeds.title;
    //console.log(embeds.title); // logging to console ✅
    let fields = embeds.fields;
    fields.forEach((field) => {
      //console.log(field.name); // logging to console ✅
      //console.log(field.value); // logging to console ✅
      fieldName = field.name;
      fieldValue = field.value;
    });
    let embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed().addFields(fieldName, fieldValue)
    ChannelAprovada.send(embed1)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You used the [`MessageEmbed#addFields`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=addFields) method (with an `s`) which requires objects as arguments. Changing it to [`MessageEmbed#addField`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=addField) should work

```js
let embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .addField(fieldName, fieldValue) //no "s"
```

Comment: It says the message is empty

Comment: what version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: I'm using the v16.11.0

Comment: @Maker__ it's your node.js version, and not discord.js

Comment: Where do i find that?

Comment: Go to your package.json -> find "dependencies" -> find "discord.js" -> it should say "^xxx". Tell me what xxx is

Answer (score 0):

Try another.

```
.addFields({ name: `text`, value: `text`})
```

For discord v.13

```
.addField("text", "text")
```

Comment: .addFields is used for Discord v.12, but in v.13 is using for multiple fields, so i agree about it.

Comment: Oh that's the point, i have to print multiples fields from the old message embed, for example: name; lastname; age || But like that is not even printing and says the filds are empty

Comment: @Maker__ did you find your discord.js version?

Comment: If you are using discord v.12, it might help you, but if you are using discord v.13, it'll be another

Comment: I'm using the 13.2.0

Comment: Then use .addField("text", "text")

Comment: @Maker__ embed sending has changed. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69540632/15781079)

Comment: @Maker__  I have edit my answer, you can test rn (Btw, i tested it in my own repl).

Answer (score 0):

As @MrMythical said, changing [MessageEmbed#addFields](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=addFields) to [MessageEmbed#addField](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=addField) should help you, but instead of `.addField(fieldName, fieldValue)` try to use `` .addField(fieldName, `** ** ${fieldValue}`) ``! Using `** **` should help you prevent getting an error even if your `fieldValue` is empty for some reason!

Also in discord.js v13 you have to use `ChannelAprovada.send({embeds: [embed1]})` instead of `ChannelAprovada.send(embed1)` to send an embed!