# I have this error when i execute my lyrics command : DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Hi can someone help me I have this error when I run my command lyrics: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
(it's a music bot that uses a command handler)
you can contact me on discord : R Λ Z#9217

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const lyricsFinder = require("lyrics-finder");

module.exports = {
      name: "lyrics",
    aliases: ['ly'],
    category: "Music",
    description: "View the lyrics of a song",
    args: false,
    usage: "",
    permission: [],
    owner: false,
    player: true,
    inVoiceChannel: true,
    sameVoiceChannel: true,
execute: async (message, args, client, prefix) => {
  
  const player = message.client.manager.get(message.guild.id);
  
  if (!player.queue.current) {
    let thing = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("RED")
        .setDescription("There is no music playing.");
    return message.channel.send(thing);
  }

    let lyrics = null;
    const title = player.queue.current
    try {
      lyrics = await lyricsFinder(player.queue.current.title, "");
      if (!lyrics) lyrics = `No lyrics found for ${title}.`, { title: title }
    } catch (error) {
      lyrics = `No lyrics found for ${title}.`, { title: title }
    }

    let lyricsEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`${title} - Lyrics`, { title: title })
      .setDescription(`${lyrics}`)
      .setColor("#F8AA2A")
      .setTimestamp();

      if (lyricsEmbed.description.length >= 2048)
      lyricsEmbed.description = `${lyricsEmbed.description.substr(0, 2045)}...`;
      return message.channel.send(lyricsEmbed).catch(console.error);
        
  }
};
```

Comment: What's your discord.js version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js v12 code breaks when upgrading to v13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69540632/discord-js-v12-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v13)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to v13 will cause a lot of errors because of breaking changes!
You can find them all listed in the guide right [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#before-you-start).
But in your case, it was about how Discord.js handles parameters with the `channel.send()`.

```
 - channel.send(embed);
 + channel.send({ embeds: [embed, embed2] });

 - channel.send('Hello!', { embed });
 + channel.send({ content: 'Hello!', embeds: [embed, embed2] });
```