# problem trying to send a client.reply as an embed Message with discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

actually i´m working and learning about discord.js and node.js to make a bot, but i have a simple issue, and i don´t know why the embed messages doesn´t work, i tried with the documentarion examples and code of other devs, but in all cases when i try to send the message to a channel, using client.reply(embed) throws me an error saying me that can send an empty message.

i´m using the last version of discord.js (v13.3.1) and i´m using the basic documentation event and the command handlers (works perfectly if i don´t try to send embeds).

This is my index.js and my help.js files:

```
//This is my index.js i don´t have problem with this but i include it if there are an issue related with this topic.

const fs = require('fs');
const { Client, Collection, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
const { token } = require('./config.json');

client.commands = new Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./Commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./Commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return;

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return interaction.reply({ content: 'Parece que ha ocurrido algun problema con el comando.', ephemeral: true });
    }
});

const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync('./Events').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const event = require(`./Events/${file}`);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
}

client.login(token);
```

Now the help.js , this is going to be a Command, but i don´t wanna only to code the commands  using the SlashCommands, because of it i´m triying to create this as an event:

```
//This is the help command using an event
const { clientId } = require("../config.json");
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
//testx is going to store the embed message
const testx = new MessageEmbed().setTitle('Test').setDescription('Test');
module.exports = {
    name: 'messageCreate',
    execute(client) {
        //This condition determines if isn´t a message of the bot, and if the written command is !!help
        if (client.author.id !== clientId && client.content === '!!help') {
            //if the condition is true, send the embed message
            //client.reply(testx); //the problem is here.
            console.log(testx);
        }
    },
};
```

And this is the error i got from the terminal:

```
DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\ //...and more info of my dirs
```

if i print the testx const in my console, i can see the two values i setted in the const filled with the text "Test", i don´t know why isn´t work or what i need to take this to work.

Thanks and i appreciate any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js v12 code breaks when upgrading to v13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69540632/discord-js-v12-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v13)

Answer (score 0):

In V13, embeds must be sent differently.

`client.reply({embeds: [testx]});`

I also recommend editing `client` to `interaction` in your command files as it may be misleading, or to actually pass the client and interaction, as you'll most likely need to access the client at some point.

Also, you seem to be confusing `interactions` with messages.

Interactions do not have an `author` property, you must use `user` or `member`.

They also do not have a `content` property, to get an argument you must use [interaction.options](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteractionOptionResolver)

You also, as far as I can see, are not actually deploying your commands. It looks like you've merged the V12 and V13 command handler tutorial together. I reccomend reading [this](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html) tutorial again, and making sure you're doing it properly for V13.