# Checking if message author has specific permissions in Discord.js v16?

Tags: discord.js

I’m making a command that should only be ran by people that can kick or ban, assuming that the role they have is some sort of mod or admin. I’ve only seen answers for previous versions, like .hasPermissions.

what do i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69540632/discord-js-v12-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v13) (self-answered by me), `.hasPermission()` has been removed. Use `.permissions.has()` instead

```js
if (message.member.permissions.has("KICK_MEMBERS")) {
  // member HAS kick members permissions
}
```

You can also check multiple permissions at the same time. This is just an example that would probably not be used

```js
if (message.member.permissions.has(["MANAGE_GUILD", "SEND_MESSAGES"])) {
  // member HAS *BOTH* permissions to send messages and manage server
}
```

You can check all the permission flags at the discord.js docs for [`Permissions.FLAGS`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS)

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple

```js
if (message.member.permissions.has('KICK_MEMBERS') || message.member.permissions.has('BAN_MEMBERS')) {
  //your code here
}
```