# TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]

Tags: discord, discord.js

Today I tried to start my bot but I got this error :

```js
TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
[Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'
```

And this is my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js'),
  client = new Discord.Client(),
  nodeHtmlToImage = require('node-html-to-image'),
  config = require('./config.json'),
  puppeteer = require('puppeteer'),
  express = require('express'),
  app = express()
var mime = require('mime'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  path = require('path')
const port = 3e3
async function nitrogenerator(e, t) {
  let a = formatAMPM(new Date())
  let n = formatAMPM(new Date(Date.now() - 6e4)),
    o = await fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/testingboost.html`, 'utf8')
  ;(datatosend = o),
    (datatosend = datatosend.replace(
      'FIRSTAUTHORURL',
      e.author.displayAvatarURL()
    )),
    (datatosend = datatosend.replace('THEFIRSTAUTHOR', e.author.username)),
    (datatosend = datatosend.replace(
      'SECONDAUTHORURL',
      client.users.cache.random().displayAvatarURL()
    )),
    (datatosend = datatosend.replace('THESECONDAUTHOR', t.shift())),
    (datatosend = datatosend.replace('RESPONSETONITRO', t.join(' '))),
    (datatosend = datatosend.replace('FIRSTAUTHORDATE', 'Today at ' + n)),
    (datatosend = datatosend.replace('SECONDAUTHORDATE', 'Today at ' + a)),
    app.get('/font', function (e, t) {
      const a = `${__dirname}/Whitneyfont.woff`
      t.sendFile(a)
    }),
    app.get('/', function (e, t) {
      t.send(datatosend)
    })
  let r = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
  const s = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
    }),
    i = await s.newPage()
  await i.goto(`http://localhost:${port}`),
    await i.waitForSelector('.scrollerInner-2YIMLh')
  const d = await i.$('.scrollerInner-2YIMLh')
  let c = await d.screenshot({ type: 'png' })
  await s.close()
  const l = new Discord.MessageAttachment(c, 'NitroProof.png')
  e.channel.send(`${e.author}`, l), r.close()
}
function formatAMPM(e) {
  var t = e.getHours(),
    a = e.getMinutes(),
    n = t >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM'
  return (t = (t %= 12) || 12) + ':' + (a = a < 10 ? '0' + a : a) + ' ' + n
}
client.on('ready', () => {
  function randomStatus() {
    let status = ['ShadowWLX#0001', 'Hehe Boy'] // You can change it whatever you want.
    let rstatus = Math.floor(Math.random() * status.length)

    // client.user.setActivity(status[rstatus], {type: "WATCHING"});
    // You can change the "WATCHING" into STREAMING, LISTENING, and PLAYING.
    // Example: streaming

    client.user.setActivity(status[rstatus], {
      type: 'LISTENING',
      url: 'https://discord.gg/MZUHeefXqx',
    })
  }
  setInterval(randomStatus, 5000) // Time in ms. 30000ms = 30 seconds. Min: 20 seconds, to avoid ratelimit.

  console.log('Online.')
})

client.on('message', async (e) => {
  if ('dm' === e.channel.type) return
  if (e.author.bot) return
  if (0 !== e.content.indexOf(config.prefix)) return
  const t = e.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g)
  'boost' === t.shift().toLowerCase() && (await nitrogenerator(e, t))
}),
client.login(config.token)
```

I know I need to add intents but I don't know how and what intents to add. I think I need to add the `GUILD_PRESENCE` intent but I don't know how to add it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js v12 code breaks when upgrading to v13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69540632/discord-js-v12-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v13)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add intents to the Client like this-

```
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: ["GUILD"] //If you want to add all intents just type 32767 instead of array
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add intents in main.js, where you initialize bot.

```
    const myIntents = new Intents();
myIntents.add(Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS);

const client = new Client({ intents: myIntents });
```

List of all intents

```
GUILDS
GUILD_MEMBERS
GUILD_BANS
GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS
GUILD_INTEGRATIONS
GUILD_WEBHOOKS
GUILD_INVITES
GUILD_VOICE_STATES
GUILD_PRESENCES
GUILD_MESSAGES
GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS
GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING
DIRECT_MESSAGES
DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS
DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING
GUILD_SCHEDULED_EVENTS
```